# Copy value of short array to long array

Tags: c

The following is an example showing what I want:

```
int buf[3] = {10, 20, 30};
int * send_buf = (int *)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

*send_buf = 1;
*(send_buf + 4) = 1;
```

After copy buf to send_buf, the values in send_buf should be :

```
1 10 20 30 1
```

Could anyone let me know what's the most efficient way to do this without using `memcpy()` or `memmove()`?

Comment: why don't you want to use `memcpy`?

Comment: `send_buf[1] = buf[0]; send_buf[2] = buf[1]; send_buf[3] = buf[2];` Also don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. It is, at best, redundant, and may hide an error the compiler would catch otherwise.

Comment: [The curious pattern of pre-emptively rejecting the solution to your problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963898/faster-alternative-to-memcpy

Answer (score 1):

Try the following changes-

```
int buf[3] = {10, 20, 30};
int * send_buf = (int *)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

*send_buf = 1;
for(i=1;i<=3;i++) // this will work for you. 
*(send_buf+i)=buf[i-1];
*(send_buf + 4) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation of memcpy() is:

```
memcpy(uint8_t *dest, uint8_t *src, size_t num_bytes) {
    for (size_t i=0; i<num_bytes; ++i)
        dest[i] = src[i];
}
```

So, since we can't use `memcpy()` for no good reason, let's just inline the body:

```
int buf[3] = {10, 20, 30};
int *send_buf = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

send_buf[0] = 1;
send_buf[4] = 1;
for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    send_buf[i + 1] = buf[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one can always do it with `sprintf` and `sscanf`

```
char buffer[1024];

sprintf(buffer, "%d %d %d", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2]);
sscanf(buffer, "%d%d%d", send_buf[1], send_buf[2], send_buf[3]);
```