# Efficient way to copying array of pointer to another pointer

Tags: c

How to copy array of pointer to another pointer.

My approach this way

```
int *ptr2[(i-1)*100];
int *ptr1;

ptr1=&ptr2[(i-1)*100];
```

What is the efficient way to copy so that it takes less cpu cycle.

Comment: You are not "copying" an array. You only asign the address of the array to a pointer variable. That costs no CPU time (hardly). Please explain better waht you want to do.

Comment: So you're having an `ptr2` array of size `(i - 1) * 100`, and then you index it with `(i - 1) * 100`. That index is 1 too far.

Comment: "memcpy()" is the choice of weapons, when it comes to copying arrays.

Comment: I don't see why the question is being downvoted. People are always struggling with pointers and we are here to help/explain.

Comment: @Pynchia there are already a gread deal of resources of what pointers and arrays are or aren't. It's not that complicated a subject, either. So people are fed up of nonsense questions about arrays and pointers that show absolutely no research effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [faster alternative to memcpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963898/faster-alternative-to-memcpy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to duplicate (copy) `ptr2`, you need to declare `ptr1` with the proper type, allocate room for the `ptr1` array, then copy `ptr2`'s contents over to `ptr1`

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int *ptr2[(i-1)*100];
int **ptr1; // a pointer to a pointer to an int

ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(ptr2));
memcpy(ptr1, ptr2, sizeof(ptr2));
```

**Note**: this is an example. Always make sure  `malloc` has allocated the memory block before using it and free it up when it's not needed anymore (use `free`)

On the other hand, if you just want to create an alias to `ptr2`

```
int *ptr2[(i-1)*100];
int **ptr1; // a pointer to a pointer to an int

ptr1 = ptr2;
```

Comment: What do you think `sizeof(ptr2)` will return?

Comment: I see your point. siezof(ptr2) return the whole array occupation. (i.e. intsize*(i-1)*100). Please feel free to describe the accurate wording then. Answer edited. Downvoting before discussing is impolite.

Comment: @qrdl `ptr2` is an array containing `(i-1)*100` elements of type `int*`, so `sizeof(ptr2)` will return the number of bytes occupied by that array, which will depend on the hardware architecture.  The name is confusing, as is placing the `*` next to the variable name rather than next to the `int`.  A clearer declaration might be : `int* arrayOfPointersToIntegers[(i-1)*100];`.  Overall the code in the answer will behave as intended.

Comment: @Pynchia This answer doesn't really address the question regarding the efficiency of using `memcpy` as opposed to some other, hand-spun technique.  I suspect that most implementations of `memcpy` (being a library function) are pre-optimised for performance, although in embedded software this isn't always true for some specific tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`memcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) to copy values-

```
int *ptr2[(i-1)*100];
int **ptr1;

prt1=malloc(sizeof(ptr2));     //also remember to free allocated memory.

memcpy(ptr1,ptr2,sizeof(ptr2));
```

Comment: Why do you cast the result of `sizeof` ? `malloc` and `memcpy` both take in the `size_t` that `sizeof` provides.

Comment: @Quentin  Yes I see that this cast is unnecessary.Thank you !!

Comment: are you sure about the type of `ptr1`?

Comment: @Pynchia  Umm... pretty sure. Why is there a problem?

Comment: according to your declaration `int *ptr1`, ptr1 is a pointer to an integer. But `ptr2` is an array of pointers (to an integer), not an array of integers.

Comment: @Pynchia Yes I am aware of that. But we are copying value aren't we. So I don't think there will be any problem .Please correct if I am wrong here.

Comment: @Pynchia Ohh got it what I did .Foolish of me .Thanks you !!