# mmap on /proc/pid/mem

Tags: c, linux, mmap, procfs, systems-programming

Has anybody succeeded in mmap'ing a /proc/pid/mem file with Linux kernel 2.6?  I am getting an ENODEV (No such device) error.  My call looks like this:

```
char * map = mmap(NULL, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, mem_fd, offset);
```

And I have verified by looking at the /proc/pid/maps file while debugging that, when execution reaches this call, offset has the value of the top of the stack minus PAGE_SIZE.  I have also verified with ptrace that mmap is setting errno to ENODEV.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See [`proc_mem_operations` in `/usr/src/linux/fs/proc/base.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2.9/source/fs/proc/base.c#L908): `/proc/.../mem` does not support `mmap`.

The respecitve linux kernel source can be installed via the `linux-source` package or by sourcing it directly from [kernel.org](https://kernel.org)