Can I share eBPF mmaped memory between root process and other non-root process
I have a tracepoint eBPF program and userspace program that reads from BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY which is mmap'ed and BPF_F_MMAPABLE -- this program ofcourse needs elevated priveleges and there is no way around it.
However, I would like to read from that mmap'ed pointer to memory from other, non-root process. Is there a way to achieve it?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447195/unix-sharing-already-mapped-memory-between-processes - "not really" (no "re-exports" for mmap'ed memory, as this is a security issue; you could theoretically use a debugger / ptrace() but that's obviousy not very efficient). So unless you find a way to entitle your non-root process to access the BPF map as well, nope :-(
