# Reading process memory (mmap, /proc/<pid>/mem)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, malloc, mmap

I'm trying to read a process's memory by reading `/proc/<pid>/mem`.
My code works as expected when I'm using

```
char *data = malloc(123456);
read(fd_mem, buffer, 123456);
```

But that can take a lot of time because of the `malloc/read` call, if the chuck of memory is really big. That's why I'm trying to switch to `mmap`. I did some test code and it kept failing until I googled about mmaping `/proc/<pid>/mem` and I realized that it's not possible (or is it?).

So my question is: How can I read the data inside `/proc/<pid>/mem` like if it was a block of memory without the delay caused by `malloc/read`

EDIT: I need access to the entire block of memory. I do not want to read N bytes at a time.

EDIT: I already saw [mmap on /proc/pid/mem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216326/mmap-on-proc-pid-mem). That question doesn't have an answer, it just says /proc/mem doesn't support mmap, which I already know. I'm asking for a solution.

Comment: @AdamMaras That question doesn't have an answer, it just says /proc/mem doesn't support mmap, which I already know. I'm asking for a solution. Please remove your close vote...

Comment: Maybe worth looking at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux

Comment: @Duck Thank you for the link, but anyways, I already know what /mem and /maps represent and that I should ptrace ATTACH/DETACH before/after reading the memory block. The code example in there is using ```read```, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid because it's slow.

Comment: See [man `splice()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice).  Of course you need a buffer otherwise.  The memory in the process is changing at the same time you are trying to read it.

Comment: @artlessnoise But ```splice``` will allow me to "copy" from one fd to another. What I want is to access the data fom the fd as if it was a memory block.

Comment: And that is to the point that the memory will constantly be changing.  Not just the values, but things will be mapped/unmapped.  Look at [linux-nat.c](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/linux-nat.c;hb=HEAD), which is the GDB *native* layer for Linux.  At line 4148 they are using `pread()`.  So if you find a faster way, you might contact them.

Comment: If you have control over the other processes code, you can have it setup shared memory.  But it sounds like you want to do this generically.  `mmap` is the way to do what you want and it is not allowed.

Comment: @artlessnoise But the process's memory won't change even a single bit as I use ptrace_attach! That sends a STOP signal to the process.

Comment: You maybe able to have the process `mmap()` the memory directly if you are using the ptrace interface.  I guess that you can execute code in the context of that pid?  At least you could re-write memory and execute some code in it's context and then revert the code back again before resuming.  The */proc/pid/mem* probably can not assume the process is stopped.