# Getting "Bad file descriptor" error when trying to mmap BAR-0 of device

Tags: c, debian, mmap, virtual-address-space

I am trying to mmap BAR-0 of a PCI device to the virtual address space in order to read (and later modify) its contents. However when I mmap it, I get the following error:

```
Path to BAR-0: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/resource0
Error at line 42, file src/main.c (9) [Bad file descriptor]
```

I am using Debian 9.1 32-Bit. The code I use is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "../include/eeprom.h"
#include "../include/pci.h"
#include "../include/i2c.h"
#include "../include/types.h"

#define PRINT_ERROR \
    do { \
        fprintf(stderr, "Error at line %d, file %s (%d) [%s]\n", \
        __LINE__, __FILE__, errno, strerror(errno)); exit(1);\
    } while(0)

#define MAP_SIZE 4096
#define MAP_MASK (MAP_SIZE - 1)

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    uint32_t pci_dev;
    void *mmap_base;
    char *file = {"/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/resource0"};
    int i;

    printf ("Path to BAR-0: %s\n", file);

    //Open Bar-0 of PCI device
    pci_dev = open (file, O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
    if (pci_dev < 0)
    {
        PRINT_ERROR;
    }

    //Map BAR-0 from physical memory to virtual address space
    mmap_base = mmap (NULL, MAP_SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, pci_dev, 0);
    if (mmap_base == (void *)-1 || mmap_base == NULL)  //error here
    {
        PRINT_ERROR;
    }
    printf ("Mapped on address %p of size %d Byte\n", mmap_base, MAP_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

I can already say, that I removed the Kernel Module used by the device, so this isn't the problem.

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mmap on /proc/pid/mem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216326/mmap-on-proc-pid-mem)

Comment: The error number reported seems surprising, but not so much the overall failure of the `mmap()` call.  `mmap()` does not work on just any open file descriptor -- ordinarily the FD must be open on a *regular* file or a shared-memory object.  However, when passed an FD referencing an unsupported kind of object, it ought to signal `EACCES`, not `EBADF`.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue while I was learning Linux Kernal programming. Running the program with superuser permission worked for me.

Comment: This worked, my file had the incorrect permissions 444 (which I assumed to mean read/write for all users, but actually means execute only for all users :P)