# Get the copy-on-write behaviour of fork()ing, without fork()

Tags: c, fork, copy-on-write

I have a large buffer:

```
char *buf = malloc(1000000000); // 1GB
```

If I forked a new process, it would have a buf which shared memory with the parent's buf until one or the other wrote to it.  Even then, only one new 4KiB block would need to be allocated by the kernel, the rest would continue to be shared.

I'd like to make a copy of buf, but I'm only going to change a little of the copy.  I'd like copy-on-write behaviour without forking.  (Like you get for free when forking.)

Is this possible?

Comment: sure, but it won't be 'for free' - you'll have to your own memory management and keep track of changes.

Comment: Yes, I want 'for free'.  I was wondering whether there were any mmap based solutions, or maybe something I hadn't even imagined.

Comment: Perhaps mmap with MAP_ANONYMOUS and MAP_PRIVATE would do the job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I do a copy-on-write memcpy in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565177/can-i-do-a-copy-on-write-memcpy-in-linux)

Comment: `1000000000` Byte is not 1 GB. It should be `1073741824` (1024 * 1024 * 1024).

Comment: @wabepper it depends on whose definition you go by. According to microsoft windows, yes, that's the case, but, according to more recent versions of Mac OSX, it IS 1 GB. There isn't that big of a difference, and in most situations the difference is marginal, at the point which you are storing that amount of information.

Comment: Also, I just wanted to say MOO!

Comment: @wabepper (feeding the troll) 10^9 bytes == 1 GB, 2^30 bytes == 1 GiB.  Giga is an SI prefix.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965505/allocating-copy-on-write-memory-within-a-process tl;dr: it's difficult on Linux.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll want to create a file on disk or a POSIX shared memory segment (`shm_open`) for the block. The first time, map it with `MAP_SHARED`. When you're ready to make a copy and switch to COW, call `mmap` again with `MAP_FIXED` and `MAP_PRIVATE` to map over top of your original map, and with `MAP_PRIVATE` to make the second copy. This should get you the effects you want.

Comment: That looks very encouraging, but I can't get it to work.  I get a bus error (on line 13).  fd == 3.  Could you point out my stupid mistake?  https://gist.github.com/2924412

Comment: You need `ftruncate` to give the shared memory segment a size. The initial size is zero.

Comment: Thanks, I added an ftruncate and now have a segfault instead of a bus error, still at line 14.

Comment: I suspect the crash is actually at line 17 where you write to the buffer. Your debug printf's are useless because you're not flushing output and they don't even end in `\n`..

Comment: Or it could even be way down. Your use of `MAP_FIXED` is wrong. You The second call to `mmap` should have `MAP_FIXED`, if you intend on making further modifications through `buf`, but you need to pass `buf` instead of `NULL` as the first argument in that case. As it stands, both of your `mmap` calls with `MAP_FIXED` are trying to map at the 0 address, which probably fails (you're not checking any return values!) and then you end up trying to use `MAP_FAILED` (usually defined as `(void *)-1`) as if it were a valid pointer.

Comment: The final `mmap` call should NOT have `MAP_FIXED` since you want a new virtual address for it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  This will take me a few minutes to get right.

Comment: It works!  https://gist.github.com/2924412  Whay was the point of the commented out remapping of buf?  I don't seem to need it.  Many thanks.

Comment: If you don't to the re-mapping of `buf` and modify `buf` *after* making the new private mapping but *before* modifying the corresponding page in `buf2`, it's possible that your changes to `buf` will wrongly show up in `buf2`. If you never intend to modify `buf` after making `buf2`, you can skip re-mapping `buf` private. But if you want to be able to modify them both without making your program randomly misbehave, you need to private re-mapping of `buf`.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.  I just need a series of 'frozen' buffers and one which I can mutate.

Comment: AFAIU, it does not work. It might work on some OSes but on Linux, when you modify the original MAP_SHARED mapping, the MAP_PRIVATE will still see the pages backing the real file. The MAP_PRIVATE pages will only "fork" from the file when the data is modified via the MAP_PRIVATE VMA.

Comment: Not if you write to the private map first.