# Find physical memory address from virtual memory address

Tags: c, linux, unix, memory-management

- On Unix systems, can I find the physical memory address for a given virtual memory address? If yes, how?

---

The real problem I'm trying to solve is, how can I find out if the OS maps two virtual addresses to the exact same physical region?

E.g. in the below `smaps` example, how do I know if both memory regions are, in fact, physically identical?

```
cat /proc/<pid>/smaps

...
7f7165d42000-7f7265d42000 r--p 00000000 00:14 641846                     /run/shm/test (deleted)
Size:            4194304 kB
Rss:             4194304 kB
Pss:             2097152 kB
...
VmFlags: rd mr mw me nr sd 
7f7265d42000-7f7365d42000 rw-s 00000000 00:14 641846                     /run/shm/test
Size:            4194304 kB
Rss:             4194304 kB
Pss:             2097152 kB
...
VmFlags: rd wr sh mr mw me ms sd 
...
```

*Bonus:* Is there a way to simply do it programmatically in **C** ?

I tried to look for duplicates but could not find a pertinent one.

Comment: If there isn't a way then you could certainly write a kernel module to provide an interface to find out, but I'm curious why you'd want to find out? Presumably, just because it's shared when you check doesn't mean it's shared a moment later.

Comment: From an application's point of view, no such thing as physical addresses exist. All addresses are virtual, and you do not know what physical address (if any! it's quite possible that no physical address exists!) they refer to. Even if you are able to determine what physical address some location refers to, this may no longer be true the next moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux you can do it by parsing files in `/proc/<pid>`, namely, `maps` and `pagemap`. There is a little user-space tool that does it for you [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/plain/Documentation/vm/page-types.c?h=linux-2.6.32.y).

Compile it (no special options are needed), run `page-types -p <pid> -l -N`, find the virtual page address in the first column, read the physical address in the second column.

It should be straightforward to turn this into a library and use programmatically. Bear in mind that some operations of the utility require root access (such as reading `/proc/kpageflags`), however, none is needed for this task.