# Copy via mmap speed?

Tags: linux, performance, mmap, memcpy, copy-on-write

An answer to this question:

[Can I do a copy-on-write memcpy in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565177/can-i-do-a-copy-on-write-memcpy-in-linux)

suggests one can achieve copy-on-write of a bunch of memory by:

1. opening a file
2. `mmap()`'ing the source to a file
3. `mmap()`'ing the destination to the same file (with `MAP_PRIVATE`)

But this seems rather fishy w.r.t. speed. I'm sure the I/O costs you something; and maybe there's more unforeseen overhead other than page table work.

So, what can be said with certainty about the speed of this procedure (perhaps as a function of the Linux kernel version)?

Comment: There's no I/O, just copying memory pages and adjusting page tables.

Comment: @Barmar: Well, you have to open a file on disk. You could say that's a "preprocessing step", I suppose.

Comment: Yes, I thought you were asking about I/O during the copying.